# assignment of values in stack variable of bison

Tags: c++, string, char

I apologize beforehand if this question sounds stupid.
How do i concatenate the input say, `a+b` and assign it to the $$ variable.
Basically i want to do $$ = $1 + $2 + $3.
I have tried a number of approaches but nothing works.

demo.y file

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>  
#include<string.h>
#include "SymbolTable.h"
#include "SymbolInfo.h"
#include "ScopeTable.h"
//#define yydebug 1

int yyparse(void);
int yylex(void);
extern char * yytext;
extern FILE * yyin;
extern int tableSize;

SymbolTable *table;

void yyerror (const char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",s);
    return;
}

%}

%debug
%verbose
%error-verbose
%union tag {
    SymbolInfo *sym;
    char *s;
}

%token <sym> ID ADDOP
%type <s> start
%type <sym> program variable

%%
    start : program {
        printf("start : program\n");
        printf("%s\n",$$);

    }

    program : variable ADDOP variable {
        printf("program : variable ADDOP variable\n");
        string str = " ";
        string str1 = $1 -> getName().c_str();

        int len = str.length();
        for(int itr = 0; itr < str1.length(); itr++)
        {
            str[len++] = str1[itr];
        }

        str1 = $2 -> getName().c_str();
        for(int itr = 0; itr < str1.length(); itr++)
        {
            str[len++] = str1[itr];
        }

        str1 = $3 -> getName().c_str();
        for(int itr = 0; itr < str1.length(); itr++)
        {
            str[len++] = str1[itr];
        }

        $$ -> setName(str);


        printf("%s\n",$$ );
    }
    variable : ID {

    }

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    table = new SymbolTable();
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }

    yyin = fp;
    yyparse();
    return 0;

}
```

**why is assigning `$$ -> setName(str)` wrong?**
$$ is of SymbolInfo* type ,as i have declared, and `setName(string s)` is a function of that class.

SymbolInfo.h

```
#ifndef SYMBOLINFO_H
#define SYMBOLINFO_H

#include <iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
extern int tableSize;
extern FILE *logout;



class SymbolInfo
{
    string Name;
    string Type;
    SymbolInfo *next;

public:
    SymbolInfo();
    void setName(string name);
    void setType(string type);
    string getName();
    string getType();
    SymbolInfo* getNext();
    void setNext(SymbolInfo *ob);

};
 #endif // SYMBOLINFO_H
```

SymbolInfo constructor

```
SymbolInfo::SymbolInfo()
{
    Name = NULL;
    Type = NULL;
    next = NULL;

   cout<<"in constructor of SymbolInfo\n"<<endl;
}
```

original error msg

```
 program : variable ADDOP variable
./script.sh: line 11:  8172 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./demo.out input.txt
```

error msg when `$$.sym ->setName(str)` is called.

```
    demo.y: In function ‘int yyparse()’:
demo.y:68:16: error: request for member ‘sym’ in ‘yyval.tag::sym’, which is of pointer type ‘SymbolInfo*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
    $$.sym-> setName(str);

  program : variable ADDOP variable
./script.sh: line 11:  8049 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./demo.out input.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so my friend debugged it finally. There were a lot of silly errors actually.

1. In the flex file i set the value of `yylval.sym` to a SymbolInfo* arr

   ```
   {id}    {

   SymbolInfo *arr = new SymbolInfo();
   arr->setName(string(strdup(yytext)));
   yylval.sym = arr;   

   return ID;

   }
   ```
2. In the bison file, i did

   ```
       program : variable ADDOP variable {
       printf("program : variable ADDOP variable\n");

       string str = $1 ->getName() + $2 -> getName() + $3 ->getName();
       $$ ->setName(str);
       cout<<$$ -> getName()<<endl;

   }
   ```
3. There was a mistake in setting the type of start non-terminal.It should be `%type< sym >start`